# Singleton and inheritance overriding

Tags: python, inheritance, singleton

I m stumbling upon singleton and multiple inheritance.

In the following code if i create **slow_grizzly** first i got the expected results.

But if i create **alaska_bear** first the **slow_grizlly** is completelely overridden by **alaska_bear**.

Not sure why is this happening, or if i m missing something.

```
class Singleton():
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls.__instance


class Animal(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, *args, is_white=False, **kwargs):
        self.is_white = is_white


class Bear(Animal):
    def __init__(self, region=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.region = region


class Grizzly(Bear):
    def __init__(self, max_speed, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.max_speed = max_speed


alaska_bear = Bear("Alaska")
slow_grizzly = Grizzly(44, region="Colorado", is_white=False)

print(alaska_bear.__dict__) #{'is_white': False, 'region': 'Alaska'}
print(slow_grizzly.__dict__)#expected {'is_white': False, 'region': 'Colorado', 'max_speed': 44} 
#but got {'is_white': False, 'region': 'Alaska'}
```

Comment: A true singleton is only going to have one instance, so it shouldn't be surprising that it has the same attributes everywhere.

Comment: @MarkRansom, ok but if i change the order of objects created is not behaving like a singletion(different outputs).

Comment: it seems that instantiating a child(Grizzly) first and then the parent(Bear) the singleton is not working for the parent; if the  parent(Bear)  is instantiated first though, and then the child(Grizzly) the singleton is working as expected also for inherited classes.